CORS error while trying to connect socket.io between next.js frontend and nest.js backend
//Backend*
    import {
WebSocketGateway,
WebSocketServer,
OnGatewayConnection,
OnGatewayDisconnect,
SubscribeMessage,
MessageBody,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import {
    Server,
    Socket
} from 'socket.io';
type Message = {
    message: string;
};
@WebSocketGateway({
    namespace: 'chat',
    cors: {
        origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
        credentials: true,
    },
})
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
    @WebSocketServer()
    server: Server;
    constructor() {}
    async handleConnection(client: Socket) {
        try {
            console.log('hello');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Unauthorized connection attempt.');
            client.disconnect();
        }
    }
    handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
        // console.log(`User ${client.data.user?.id} disconnected.`);
        console.log('bye');
    }
    @SubscribeMessage('events')
    handleEvent(@MessageBody() data: Message): Message {
        console.log({
            data
        });
        return {
            message: 'ok'
        };
    }
}

//***Frontend
 import { io, Socket } from "socket.io-client";

const SOCKET_URL = "http://localhost:4000/chat";

let socket: Socket | null = null;

export const getSocket = (): Socket => {
  if (!socket) {
    socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }

  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Connected to WebSocket server:");
  });

  return socket;
};

I failed to understand where I was wrong in getting the CORS issue.
Is there anything I'm missing? I tried to change to a different port in the socket config, it didn't help. I'm able to connect via Postman.
The WebSocket connection seemed successful (status 200), but the browser rejected it due to a CORS policy violation.
please share your thoughts on the matter
